# Routing optional parameters in Adonis

Tags: api, rest, routes, localhost, adonis.js

My overall goal is to get all jobs associated with a user.

This is my routing code in routes.ts

```js
Route.get('/job/:homeowner_id?', 'JobsController.index')
```

This is my JobsController.index code inside JobsController

```js
public async index({params, response}: HttpContextContract) {
    // If homeowner_id is passed in
    if (params) {
      const jobs = await Job
      .query()
      .select('id', 'status', 'contractor_id', 'address', 'homeowner_id', 'fence_material', 'fence_drawing_data', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
      .where('homeowner_id', params.homeowner_id)
       const index = {'total':jobs.length, 'jobs':jobs}
       return response.status(200).json(index)

    }
    // To return ALL jobs in database (probably won't be used)
    const jobs = await Job
    .query()
    .select('id', 'status', 'contractor_id', 'address', 'homeowner_id', 'fence_material', 'fence_drawing_data', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    .orderBy('created_at', 'asc')

    const index = {'total':jobs.length, 'jobs':jobs}
    return response.status(200).json(index)
  }
```

Using Insomnia (*Postman alternative*), when I try to send a GET request to:

- http://localhost:3333/job
- http://localhost:3333/job?homeowner_id=1

both of these return the error:

```
    "message": "\".where\" expects value to be defined, but undefined is passed",
    "stack": "Exception: \".where\" expects value to be defined, but undefined is passed\n    at ModelQueryBuilder.validateWhereSingleArgument...
```

What is needing to be changed here in order for the optional parameter to work and lack of parameter to work?

Comment: You can always send query parameters. Parameter is inside url. So your route would be /job/1 or just /job. Deconstruct {params} in controller from context

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up query parameters and params, it should be:

```js
public async index({params, response}: HttpContextContract) {
    // If homeowner_id is passed in
    if (params.homeowner_id) {
      // Do you job if homeowner ID is exist

    }
    
    // Otherwise return all
  }
```

And send request with param or without:

- http://localhost:3333/job
- http://localhost:3333/job/1